# How can I strip the following values with numerous amounts of spaces in-between each value in this .txt file?

Tags: python

I am trying to strip relevant information from this .txt file. There are numerous amounts of .txt files to strip from so creating a function or class or an ideal automated approach is needed to automate this task. This is the .txt file I am working with:

```
NET CASH                      3575.50    NET CASH                      3575.50    CASH SALES                    3575.50
LESS COMMISSIONS               691.03    NET CREDIT                   13429.59    CASH REFUNDS                      .00
                                         TOTAL                        17005.09    NET ADJUSTMENTS                   .00
NET REMITTANCE                2884.47                                             AAD S                             .00
                                         FARES                        12442.61    NET CASH                      3575.50
                                         TOTAL                        17005.09    CREDIT REFUNDS                    .00
```

My goal is to strip the NET CASH, CASH SALES, LESS COMMISSIONS, NET CREDIT, TOTAL, NET REMITTANCE primarily.
How should I approach this? I have noticed that each value is separated after .(digit)(digit) followed by "    " amount of spaces.

This is the code I am using so far to create this .txt file:

```
file1 = open('MasterFile.txt', 'r')

file2 = open('StrippedMasterFileUpdated.txt', 'w')

for lines in file1.readlines():
    if lines.__contains__('NET CASH') or  lines.__contains__('TOTAL') or lines.__contains__('CASH SALES') or lines.__contains__('NET CASH') or lines.__contains__('LESS COMMISSIONS') or lines.__contains__('NET REMITTANCE'):
        file2.write(lines)
```

Here is the expected output:

3575.50\n
3575.50\n
691.03\n
13429.59\n
13429.59\n
17005.09\n
2884.47

Anything helps!

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: These .txt files represent a week by week basis of sales; I was thinking that I can create a list that would append the value of the file in a column

Comment: So one list would be NET CASH 3575.5, XXXX.XX, XXX.XX, ...

Each value would represent their week (which would equate to a total of 52 values)

The same would go on for each other category such as TOTAL, LESS COMMISSIONS, etc

Thinking out loud here

Comment: when requested, please provide the exact expected output, in the question, as text, and that matches the input, not a vague description as comment. This is important for reproducibility

Comment: Got it! Thank you Mozway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use regex to solve this.

First things first check remove all the whitespace in each line:

```
line = re.sub(r"[\s]+", " ", line)
```

Next check for your desired words and the numbers that follow:

```
regex = r"(NET CASH|CASH SALES|LESS COMMISSIONS|NET CREDIT|TOTAL|NET REMITTANCE)( [0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
results = re.findall(regex, line)
```

Results then contains a list of all the matches. Running this on the first line of your example gives:

```
print(results) # Prints -> [('NET CASH', '3575.50'), ('NET CASH', '3575.50'), ('CASH SALES', '3575.50')]
```

Then you can process this data as needed.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the feedback Sam. Due to being new here, it wont allow me to upvote currently due to being a week here on the platform but I appreciate your time!

Comment: It did record my feedback however
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Without removing whitespace first: `r'(NET CASH|CASH SALES|LESS COMMISSIONS|NET CREDIT|TOTAL|NET REMITTANCE)[^\d]*([0-9]+\.\d{2})'`

Comment: Sam,
re.sub worked, it removed all white spaces

However, 
Currently when I print(results) it is not printing anything but an empty set of square brackets 

I have the re library imported aka:
import re

Trying to debug but am stumped

Comment: Could you comment your code for me to take a look at?

Comment: for lines in file1.readlines():
    if lines.__contains__('AGENT SALES SUMMARY') or lines.__contains__('NET CASH') or lines.__contains__('CASH SALES') or lines.__contains__('NET CASH') or lines.__contains__('LESS COMMISSIONS') or lines.__contains__('NET REMITTANCE'):
        line = re.sub(r"[\s]+", " ", lines)
        regex = r"(NET CASH|CASH SALES|LESS COMMISSIONS|NET CREDIT|TOTAL|NET REMITTANCE)( [0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
        results = re.findall(regex, line)
        file2.write(line)



print(results)

Comment: Sorry for the formatting

Comment: tried moving the regex = ... and results = ... outside of the if statement and still empty brackets

Comment: could you please try printing out a line and putting the output here? Is working for me.

Comment: going to try to convert the file text to a string and then try again

Comment: It may not be working because it's writing it to a file and not reading it from a string

Comment: PAGE - 1 AGENT SALES SUMMARY RPT PED - 01/05/20 PAGE - 2 AGENT SALES SUMMARY RPT PED - 01/05/20 NET CASH 3575.50 NET CASH 3575.50 CASH SALES 3575.50 LESS COMMISSIONS 691.03 NET CREDIT 13429.59 CASH REFUNDS .00 NET REMITTANCE 2884.47 AAD S .00  FARES 12442.61 NET CASH 3575.50 PAGE - 3 AGENT SALES SUMMARY RPT PED - 01/05/20

Comment: That is the line from file2 ^

Comment: Hi Sam, I was right. I closed the file in write mode, opened in read mode and attached that to a variable, then used regex = ... and results =... and it worked. Thank you again for your help/collab, I hope you have an excellent rest of your day.